# SIM900D Transparent Mode to Webserver permits only to transmit once

Tags: tcp, get, webserver, put, gprs

I used this series of AT commands to be able to connect and transmit/receive data with my laptop via the SIM900D GSM/GPRS module.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2...icrocontroller

[image]

The TCP connection does not end not until either of the two endpoints decided to terminate the TCP connection.. On the other hand, when I tried to connect with our webserver (e.g. AT+CIPSTART="TCP","www.mydomain.com","80")

It achieves connection.. But if the GPRS module does not immediately send any data, soon the webserver terminates the TCP connection.. If I tried sending by sending the url (e.g. PUT /send.php?g0=21 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: dlsu-ect.com\r\n\r\n$1A\r), the webserver receives the data but it ends the terminate right after that transmission. Transparent mode only permit one transmission per TCP connection..

Am I doing it right? Is my way of transmitting the data to our webserver the right way for transparent mode?

Answer (score 0):

If your request is correctly saving data to the server, you can try to add a header which requests that the server does not close the connection immediately after responding to the first request.

Try sending:

```
PUT /send.php?g0=21 HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: dlsu-ect.com\r\n
Connection: Keep-alive\r\n
Content-length: 3\r\n
\r\n
$1A\r\n
\r\n
```

That should keep your connection alive, depending on the server configuration. As some servers do not allow keep-alive connections this might not work. You could also test keep-alive using telnet before attempting to do it on your Sim900 right away.

Also note that the timeout between requests differs a lot between servers. Some only allow a few seconds between requests.